# Pure css pop up design

Tags: html, css, popup

How to create the pop up box as shown below in image with pure css

[image]

Here is what I have made with position:absolute which works fine but what I am trying to get is, is it possible to do only with one div by using `:after` or `:before` pseudo classes?

```
.pop{
    background:#333;
    display:inline-block;
    width:250px;
    height:120px;
    border-radius:8px;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:25px
}
span{
    position:absolute; 
    left:0; 
    top:-20px;
    color:white;
    display:inline-block;
    border-radius:8px 8px 0 0;
    background:#333; 
    padding:6px;
    width:100px
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cup5Y/14/)**

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Cup5Y/10/

Comment: @Bondye pls check the updated question. I had already tried this method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one is not much flexible, but does thing without additional markup, using pseudo element `::before`.

```css
.pop {
  background: #333;
  width: 250px;
  height: 120px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.pop::before {
  content: "Pop up head";
  display: block;
  width: 90px;
  background: #333;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-top: -14px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="pop"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly this is what you need http://jsfiddle.net/slash197/Cup5Y/15/

HTML

```
<div class="holder">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="pop">asd asd asd </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.holder {
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    height: 140px;
}
.header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 20px;
    background:#333;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-top-left-radius:8px;
    border-top-right-radius:8px;
    padding: 0px 10px;
}
.pop{
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 0px;
    background:#333;
    color: #ffffff;
    display:inline-block;
    width:250px;
    height:120px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius:8px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:8px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:8px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need 2 divs, one for the "header" and one for the "content"

see my example http://jsfiddle.net/Cup5Y/13/

```
<div class="pop">
    <div class="head">
        Title
    </div>
    <div class="content">

    </div>
</div>
```